# How do I change the "href" link that corresponds with an "li class" statement?

Tags: links

Using Firebug I can see the statement -

`<li class="cat-item cat-item-72143">`

and below that is the -

`<a href="http://domain.com/category/catname">CatName</a>`

I would like to change the link with changing anything else.

Can anyone tell me where I can do this? All I can find is the css files, I can't find
where that link lives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are looking at code generated by [`wp_list_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists) based on the class names, but I can't say for sure.

If that is the case, then the link [is probably generated here](http://$link%20=%20'%3Ca%20href=%22'%20.%20esc_url(%20get_term_link(%20$category%20)%20)%20.%20'%22%20';):

```
$link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) ) . '" ';
```

Meaning that you could probably alter it with [this filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L0):

```
$termlink = apply_filters( 'category_link', $termlink, $term->term_id );
```

Proof of concept:

```
function alter_category_link($termlink) {
  return 'abcdefg';
}
add_filter( 'category_link', 'alter_category_link');
wp_list_categories();
```

Alter the link to what, I have no idea. You don't specify.

Comment: Hello - thank you for the information! I'm still unsure of exactly where to the url? I want to add a category because of where, and how, the categories are displayed in my theme. After I added the category it displays just as I want it to. Now when I click on that it brings up an empty page as there are no posts in that category. What I'd like to do is redirect that so it automatically goes to another URL. I can add a post to that category and redirect the post itself but that's not as clean as the user just clicking on the category - "Community" - and taken directly to the community site.

Comment: That is a very different question than you first asked! Please edit the question so that it clear and accurate!

Comment: I want to change the link - the "href" line - that the "li class" refers to. Can you tell me why it's different - becaue to me, nothing has changed other than me specifying what the "li" statement refers to and where I want the URL to point to. I just want to change the link - just like I said at first. Does anyone know where that link is and how I can edit it?

Comment: Then told you how to do that.

Comment: In that case it would seem to be beyond me because I'm not familiar with anything you wrote :) I was just hoping to find the link and edit it, edit the actual link. I don't know what term means or termlink or term_id, where this code would even go, or how using it would change the link from "domain.com" to "sub.domain.com"…but I appreciate your time! Thanks...

Comment: This is a complex php application. You can't always just find the link and edit it like you can with straight  html. PHP builds the markup, to alter the markup you need to alter the php.

Comment: Ah…that explains why I can never find the markup! Thank you again for your time. - Rob